# Thinkpad W510 gets slow after 5 mins of regular activity (CPU thread fully loaded)

Tags: 15.10, intel, thinkpad, cpu

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad W510. Since I got it, I always run into this problem, especially when running Ubuntu. After starting the laptop and using Chrome or Firefox with just 4-5 tabs open and eventually have Skype open (so nothing fancy), the system gets really slow. I have to reboot to get back to normal. I checked System Monitor and it looks like when having this problem, one of the CPU threads is always on full load.

[image]

When checking the "Processes" tab, I don't see any process taking more than 3% of CPU.

These are my specs:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Intel i7 Q820 @ 1.73GHZ
- 8GB RAM
- SSD Kingston V300 SATA III

I had this problem not only with Ubuntu 15, but with Ubuntu 14 as well. Tried to replace Unity with gnome & something else, with no effect. I also had Windows installed and as I remember, something was happening with that as well, but still, the situation was a bit better. I just got the SSD so it's a fresh install.

Do you have any idea why this would happen? I'm a Linux noob, btw :)

Answer (score 1):

I just bought one of these used a few weeks ago and have run into a lot of trouble with performance. Make certain you are not using a 90W power supply as the ThinkPad will throttle itself substantially. A 135W power supply was standard and ought to avail the unit's full power to you.

Mine came with a 90W supply and I noticed a dramatic increase in performance by unplugging it and running from battery power.

Comment: Indeed it looks like my power supply is 90W. And after the latest BIOS update I do get a warning message when starting the laptop saying that I'm using a non-standard supply. I'll try running it on battery and see how it goes.
Thanks for the suggestion!